# LINQ lambda expression subquery to find a parent record in the same table

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, lambda

Is it possible to do a lambda expression to run this query in C#?

```
SELECT Name
FROM Table
WHERE ID IN (SELECT ParentId FROM Table WHERE Name = 'Child')
```

So each row has an `ID` and a `ParentId`. I need to search the child record by `Name` to get the `ParentId` which is the `ID` of the parent I want to retrieve the `Name` for.

Comment: Are you using Entity Framework?

Comment: Yes, EF4. (I'm a little behind...)

Comment: Then, edit your question to show Model class to figure out how we can help you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Check this code:

```
var l = Table.Where(x => Table.Where(n => n.Name == "child")
    .Select(n => n.ParentId).Any(y => y == x.Id)).Select(y=>y.Name);
```

I used this class to test the results:

```
class Person
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int ParentId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public Person(int id, int parentId, string name)
    {
        Id = id;
        ParentId = parentId;
        Name = name;
    }
}
```

I hope it will help you.

Comment: That was perfect.  Thanks!  I can't uptick the vote because I don't have enough rep points but this is definitely the answer.